# Cucumber with Protractor - Multiple Features Not Executed Properly

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, pom

I have a pretty small POM based project for learning Cucumber with Protractor. I am using TypeScript. I am trying to perform pretty basic actions (clicking on button, clicking on a menu item) on [Angular IO](https://angular.io/) home page.

```
|    ├───e2e
│         ├───features
│         └───steps
│              ├───common
│              ├───getstarted
│              ├───learnmore
│              └───search
```

The `features` directory contains the features files for the tests. An example is here - where I want to click on the "Get Started" button to go to the quickstart page.

```
Feature: Search
    As a developer using Angular
    I need to look-up classes and guidelines
    So that I can concentrate on building awesome applications

Scenario: Click on Get Started
    Given I am on the angular.io site
    When I click on Get Started Button
    Then I should see the Get Started Page
```

The `steps` directory contains the step Definitions for the `.feature` files, with the common steps being clubbed in `common.ts` file inside `steps`.

If I run a single feature file, then the execution works perfectly fine, however, if I add multiple `.feature` in the `feature` dir, then the execution breaks and it goes haywire.

I have tried various strategies, like grouping the `.feature` and step file in one same dir, but nothing else is working.

Any pointers or help in this would be highly appreciated. A working reproducible repository is [here](https://github.com/zac11/yarn-cucumber-ts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day or two of hard toiling and trying a lot of combinations, I was able to get the features working correctly.

The issue was that the feature files and the steps were not glued together and many times, if I had the feature files along with the step definitions, it would throw an ambiguous error, since Cucumber gets multiple same definitions and is not able to actually tell which steps it had to run.

I put up an issue for the ambiguous error on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664254/multiple-step-definitions-match-error-in-cucumber), and the answer given by Kyle Fairns gave me the idea to separate the common steps at one place and after a some hours of trying things and reading a lot of blog posts, I re-structured my tests in this way -

```
|    ├───e2e
│         ├───features
|         |     |---search.feature
|         |     |---getstarted.feature
|         |     
│         └───steps
│              ├───common
|              |     |-common_step.ts [Contains Given step]
|              |
│              ├───getstarted
|              |      |---getstarted.po.ts
|              |      |---getstarted.steps.ts
│              ├───learnmore
|              |      |---learnmore.po.ts
|              | .    |---learnmore.steps.ts
│              |───search
|              |      |---search.po.ts
|              |      |---search.steps.ts
```

I grouped the `.po` and `.steps` file in a single directory for a specific action.

Since the `Given` step was common to all the scenarios, I put it up in a single `common` directory. The rest steps were separated out, action wise in their respective directory.

The `dir` structure that I am working currently gives me the flexibility of tuning out the exact steps and methods for a particular action , since the steps corresponds to particular function blocks in the `.po` files.

However, if someone comes with a better idea/structure, please feel free to add an answer to the question and I would be more than happy to try it out.